# Jquery not working in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, angular5

I tried to use **Jquery** in **Angular5** it works on one my components but not in inner components

I have imported it in app.component.ts:

`import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';`

It works inside the header section: `app/layout/components/header.`

But not into the inner components which like this: `app/layout/stores/store/store-info`

Tried to import jquery in all the modules still not working

Help Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Melchia, Thanks I have already imported jquery and its working.
It was only nor working in some of the components.

I tried this:

```
$(document).on({

// functionality

})
```

And it works now!